# Problem converting DVI file with Japanese font

Tags: cjk, dvi, dvips

I'm failing to open/convert a dvi file, which presumably contains a Japanese font I haven't installed (so much for **d**e**v**ice **i**ndependent...). Is there a way to automatically substitute the font or find out which font is needed to view/convert the file?

```
$ dvips ホモロジー的ミラー対称性の諸相.dvi 
This is dvips(k) 5.994 Copyright 2014 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2003.10.08:0824' -> ホモロジー的ミラー対称性の諸相.ps

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode ljfour --bdpi 600 --mag 2+44/600 --dpi 1244 min10
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for min10.
mktexpk: perhaps min10 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
dvips: Font min10 not found; using cmr10
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>
dvips: Checksum mismatch in font min10
dvips: ! invalid char 9563 from font min10
```

Comment: Do you have the `.tex` file, assuming this is produced from some such? That will tell you unequivocally what it is trying to use. I'm afraid that 'Device Independent' is not device-independent in the sense you have in mind... ;).

Comment: I imagine you need [ptex](http://ctan.org/pkg/ptex) or the set of additions mentioned there. On my system: `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/ptex/standard/min10.tfm` for example.

Comment: @cfr No, I don't have the `.tex` file. I found (only) the dvi file on the author's webpage. I haven't installed ptex, so I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have `min10.tfm` as part of a standard installation of TeX Live. Querying for information using `tlmgr`:

```
tlmgr search --file min10.tfm

bookhands:
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/bookhands/cmin10.tfm
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/bookhands/hmin10.tfm
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/bookhands/imin10.tfm
ptex:
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/ptex/nmin-ngoth/nmin10.tfm
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/ptex/standard/min10.tfm
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/ptex/standard/tmin10.tfm
uptex:
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/uptex/min/umin10.tfm
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/uptex/min/utmin10.tfm
```

Obviously, of these, [ptex](http://ctan.org/pkg/ptex) is the one which you want as it is the one which provides `min10.tfm`. So I imagine that installing `ptex` should help.